# Buttons are not appearing at top right

Tags: html, css

I just want to show my buttons at top right corner of the screen. I tried a lot to do so and Google it too. I also used tag of pull-right but unable to figure out why they are not appearing at the desired position. Any help? Here is my code:

```html
@{ ViewBag.Title = "ListCams"; Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; }
<style>
  div.scroll {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  button {
    background-color: Transparent;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: none;
  }
</style>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    @*
    <h1 style="color:#F4981F; font-family:'Segoe Marker'">Cams List</h1>*@
    <div class="scroll">
      <form action="/Home/Redirect">
        <div class="btn-group pull-right">
          <button name="button1" value="list" type="submit" class="button" style="width:60px; height:58px; border:none">
            <img src="~/Images/List.png" width="53" height="55" />button2</button>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
          <button name="button1" value="stream" type="submit" class="button" style="width:60px; height:58px; border:none">
            <img src="~/Images/House.png" width="53" height="55" />button2</button>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
          <button name="button1" value="setting" type="submit" class="button" style="width:60px; height:58px; border:none">
            <img src="~/Images/Settings.png" width="53" height="55" />button4</button>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
          <h1 style="color:#F4981F; font-family:'Segoe Marker'">Cams List</h1>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have checked this link too and it is working fine here but when i run my app they are appearing at top left below the heading.

---

[bootply link](http://www.bootply.com/82631)

Comment: Hello, pls give us your whole css of the form...

Comment: @lgor Laszlo now my complete css form is given.

Comment: @RabiaMehmood  try this http://www.bootply.com/FF3utMWkI8 surely work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add this css it will float on right side:

```
   .pull-right {
          float: right!important;
          margin-top: -66px;
          position: absolute;
          margin-left: 293px;
     }
```

Working fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/cpf78jsg/1/

Comment: This doesn't push it up to the top-right, only to the right hand side, leaving a gap where the title is taking up.

Comment: This fiddle is the reproducing the same problem as mentioned in question

Comment: I don't understand why this has been marked as the answer, as it doesn't solve the issue at all.

Comment: @rJ7 thanks a lot for ur help :) Can u plz tell me little bit more that what if i want the buttons on the same line as that of heading? And i m also facing issue in my other form in which i have set the text fields to be shown on the right side but they are not shown there. Although i did the same in some other form and it is working fine there.

Comment: @Rabia Mehmood Some css styles may be override your given styles. Make sure your css styles are affecting or not. If not then add !important in your respecting styles.

Comment: @RabiaMehmood can you explain why this is your answer? As I can't see how it actually solves your issue compared to the other answers? It's not good practice to use !important unless you absolutely have to, or absolute positioning. It's not a very good answer.. sorry

Comment: @rJ7 Downvoting through retribution isn't a good way of how the Stackoverflow system works, especially when it has no justification.

Comment: @Lee Downvoted bcz Your answer is not a solution as per the need of RabiaMehmood

Comment: I believe my answer is more accurate than yours is to be honest. He stated he wanted the buttons to be a the top right of the screen. Mine always were, yours aren't because they only go to the right of the container, which isn't the edge of the screen.

Comment: @Lee Oh then you deleted your answer

Comment: Yes, simply because I'm not going to be pulled into a childish war over reputation. I want scoring to stay honest and true, which it stopped being when you downvoted my question. I'm not the only person to think your answer isn't really valid. But this is now the end of my involvement with this question.

Answer (score 1):

`<h4>` is block element as like div so it covers all width.

Wrap `panel-heading` div inside row and then provided 12 column calculation to that div

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel-heading row">
    <h4 class="col-xs-9">Panel header</h4>
    <div class="btn-group pull-right col-xs-3">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">## Lock</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">## Delete</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">## Move</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Working solution with your code](http://www.bootply.com/pAQO45kFeC)

Comment: This doesn't push the buttons to the top-right of the screen

Comment: No, it's a bit more than just a few pixels.. You shouldn't be using classes, as this breaks the responsiveness

Comment: @Lee  why we shouldn't use col classes? they are also divided width in terms of pixel

Comment: True, but in your case it doesn't leave it pushed right up against the top right in my browser at full width.