# 100% height of columns in bootstrap panel

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

how can I get 100% of height for all three columns without content?

here's a jsfiddle:

```
    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="shadow panel panel-default">
      <div class="blue white-border panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title text-white">
          Contacts
        </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="col-xs-3 green">1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 red">2</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 black">3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dkvf6yka/

Comment: 100% of what? the page?

Comment: something similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28279612/buttons-are-not-appearing-at-top-right/28279745#28279745

Comment: yeah sorry i mean 100% of the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use css 'vh'

```
.col-xs-3 {
    height:100vh;
}
```

This sets the height to 100% of the viewport height

Comment: is this possible to get 100% height of the page in pure css ?

Comment: Ohhh I see, yes, I will change my answer

Comment: thats not the nicest way cause on mac there is also a scrollbar but its a good to work with :-)

Comment: 'vh'.  Brilliant.  There are so many answers to this question that just don't work.   Yay for this one.